# Convert an Int JSON value to String enum case

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Here's an simplified version of the class:

```
class Movie: Codable {
    var name: String
    var genre: MovieGenre

    init(name: String, genre: MovieGenre) {
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
    }
}

enum MovieGenre: String, Codable {
    case action
    case drama
    case horror
}
```

And the JSON:

```
{
    "name" : "Test",
    "genre" : 1
}
```

I know the relation between the JSON genre value and the `MovieGenre` enum is:

```
1 = action
2 = drama
3 = horror
```

Using `JSONDecoder`, how can I convert the JSON genre Int value to my enum `MovieGenre`?

I would like not to have to write an `init from decoder`, because it would be very verbose having to convert each attribute manually.

Here's an example:

```
let movie = Movie(name: "Test", genre: .action)
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    // encoding
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(movie)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print("JSON String : " + jsonString!) // prints: JSON String : {"name":"Test","genre":"action"}

    // decoding
    let json = "{\"name\":\"Test\",\"genre\":1}".data(using: .utf8)!
    _ = try jsonDecoder.decode(Movie.self, from: json)
} catch {
    print(error) // prints: typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "genre", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type for your enum does not match with the type in the JSON.

I changed the Type for your enum to Int and set the initial value for action (as the default would be 0) and got the expected result without custom decoding.

Trying this in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let jsonData = """
{
    "name" : "Test",
    "genre" : 1
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

class Movie: Codable {
    var name: String
    var genre: MovieGenre

    init(name: String, genre: MovieGenre) {
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
    }
}

enum MovieGenre: Int, Codable {
    case action = 1
    case drama
    case horror
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try? decoder.decode(Movie.self, from: jsonData)
print(result?.name)
print(result?.genre)
print(result?.genre.rawValue)
```

Output is:

> Optional("Test")
>
> Optional(__lldb_expr_39.MovieGenre.action)
>
> Optional(1)

This should also encode in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking about not changing the enum type to Int. Ended up doing the conversion manually on `init(from: Decoder)`.